# What am I doing wrong in solving this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $g$ be a function of $t$

$$e^{3t}g'(t)+3e^{3t}g(t)=2e^{6t}$$

Now, Divide each side by $e^{3t}$ and then multiply by the integrating factor $\mu(t)$

$$ \mu g'(t)+3\mu g(t) = 2 e^{3t} \mu$$

Now our aim is to make $\frac{d}{dt}(\mu g) = LHS$ of the equation, to satisfy this we end up with :

$$\mu'(t)= 3 \mu$$

Solving for $\mu$ using separation $$\mu = ce^{3t}$$ for this case we can say $c=1$.

Then The equation is now looks like this :

$$\frac{d}{dt}( \mu g) = 2e^{6t} \\ e^{3t}g = \frac{1}{3}e^{6t}+c \\ g= \frac{e^{3t}}{3}+ce^{-3t}$$

But the answer sheet says that $$g= 2te^{3t}+ce^{3t}$$

Is my answer wrong? Or can they both be true? If they can both be true why is this case? How do you think book has solved this question?

Comment: Why don't you just use that $$e^{3t} g' + 3 e^{3t} g = (e^{3t} g)'$$ ? Your integrating factor is already in the equation. And your answer is correct up to an initial condition.

Comment: then your answer sheet is wrong, the right answer is $$g(t)=\frac{e^{3t}}{3}+Ce^{-3t}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is correct. The answer sheet is the solution of the ODE
$$e^{3t}g'(t)-3e^{3t}g(t)=2e^{6t}$$
A small typo in the statement?

In fact, after multiplying by  $e^{-6t}$ we get
$$e^{-3t}g'(t)-3e^{-3t}g(t)=2$$
and therefore
$$D(e^{-3t}g(t))=2\implies e^{-3t}g(t)=2t+c \implies g(t))=2te^{3t}+ce^{3t}.$$